# PySpark column name of Spark data frame based on CSV

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rename

I got the following data frame:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------------+---------+
|province|           city|      infection_case|confirmed|
+--------+---------------+--------------------+---------+
|   Seoul|     Yongsan-gu|       Itaewon Clubs|      139|
|   Seoul|      Gwanak-gu|             Richway|      119|
|   Seoul|        Guro-gu| Guro-gu Call Center|       95|
|   Seoul|   Yangcheon-gu|Yangcheon Table T...|       43|
|   Seoul|      Dobong-gu|     Day Care Center|       43|
```

Now I want to change the column names (first row) based on a CSV file, which looks like this:

```
province,any_other__name
city,any_other__name      
infection_case,any_other__name
confirmed,any_other__name
```

This is my code :

```
cases = spark.read.load("/home/tool/Desktop/database/TEST/archive/Case.csv",format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")
cases = cases.select('province','city','infection_case','confirmed')
cases \
  .write \
  .mode('overwrite') \
  .option('header', 'true') \
  .csv('8.csv')
```

Comment: i found the solution 
cases = cases.selectExpr("province as otheer names1", "city as otheer names2", "confirmed as otheer names3")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use [`withColumnRenamed`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed) method.

```py
for line in open("path/to/file.csv"):
    old_name, new_name = line.strip().split(",")
    cases = cases.withColumnRenamed(old_name, new_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

solution here
Rename using selectExpr() in pyspark  uses “as” keyword to rename the column “Old_name” as “New_name”.

```
cases = cases.selectExpr("province as names1", "city as names2", "confirmed as names3")
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
# Define K,V pair in form of (old_name, new_name). Then 
# By using withColumnRenamed update all required columns

schema = {
        'province':'any_province__name',
        'city':'any_city__name',     
        'infection_case':'any_infection_case__name',
        'confirmed':'any_confirmed__name' 
      }

def rename_column(df=None,schema=None):
    for columns in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(columns,schema[columns])
    return df

df_final = rename_column(df=df,schema=schema)
```